# Cannot resolve symbol Log in Android Studio 3.4.1

Tags: android

Whenever I try to use any of the Log functions like `Log.d()`, `Log.v()`, etc. I get an error saying:

> Cannot resolve symbol Log.

Even if I write the import statement `import android.util.Log` the error still persists.

Comment: try it once invalidate cache / Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

This is the android studio issue, following help me

1. Clean & Rebuild project
2. Invalidate cache and restart